# Layout design for 21.5 inch screen android device

Tags: android, android-layout

Am developing an application for 21.5 screen android device. I have tried the code below and testing in the 10 inch emulator. its looking good. but i want to know whether is it good to use the relative layout or linear layout with weight. Because i don't want the blank space below the layout when it appears in 21,5 inch screen. Please suggest.

My layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

<com.acuvue.kiosk.view.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/please_choose"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customTextView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which device provide 21.5 inch screen ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana hp slate 21 android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here use LinearLayout with weight instead of Relativelayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.acuvue.kiosk.view.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/please_choose"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try this. Do you know any suggestion on how to test it in 21.5 screen

Comment: @BalajiDhanasekar,no idea man such type resolution even not available for emulator.

Comment: OK fine. I think it will match any screen size, if we use linear layout with weight. isn't it.

Comment: Yes please check with some of resolution and let me know